# A question about such integrations relating to winding numbers

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, winding-number

I am wondering, since

$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z
$$

can offer information about winding numbers by

$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z = \sum_{k=1}^{m} n(\gamma;a_k)
$$

for $m$ is the max multiplicity of winding numbers, then, what about the following, are they giving anything about winding numbers or zeros of the function $f(z)$:

$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{z f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z \quad \text { and } \quad \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{z^{2} f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z \quad \text { and } \quad \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{z^{3} f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z \quad \text { and } \quad \ldots
$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}g(z)\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz=\sum_{a\in Z}g(a)-\sum_{b\in P}g(b)$, where $Z,P$ are the set of zeros and poles respectively of $f$ (put appropriate hypotheses). For the proof, mimic the usual proof as in the case of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz$. So, by taking $g=1$, we see that this is the number of zeros minus number of poles. By taking $g(z)=z$, this is the sum of the zeros minus sum of poles (all counted with multiplicity). See [Generalized Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle#Generalized_argument_principle)

Comment: @peek-a-boo, is there a link for more information about the theorem?